# simple bs4 script to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

very simple Q, I have this script which I'm working on to scrape some web data:

```
for x in df['Product ID']:
search_url = 'url' + x
uclient = uReq(search_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
rp = page_soup.findAll("h2",{"class" : 'highlightValue'})[0].text.strip()
```

what would be the best way to write this outcome of the loop back into my data frame? if i Assign a new column lets call it df['Price'] it will be overwritten in each element of the loop, whereas I only want it to assign a value to x.

```
data = ['12345','6789']
pd.DataFrame({'Product ID' : data})
```

so if the price for 12345 = £25 on my website and 6789 £50 I would want to assign those back respectively, am I missing something simple?

desired output

```
Product ID  Price
12345       £25
6789        £50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = ['12345','6789']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product ID' : data}) 


for x in df['Product ID']:
    search_url = 'url' + x
    uclient = uReq(search_url)
    page_html = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
    rp = page_soup.findAll("h2",{"class" : 'highlightValue'})[0].text.strip()

    df.loc[df['Product ID'] == x,'Price'] = rp
```

the code below is selecting the rows that match the Product Id of variable x, and assigning the 'Price' column of those rows to what ever you just scraped

`df.loc[df['Product ID'] == x,'Price'] = rp`

Comment: Knew this is what I needed, just couldn't remember the syntax! It doesn't work however, the dataframe stays the same, it's not appending the values into the data (which are being pulled as I wrote a print statement to check)

Comment: I would if it worked, just tried `df.loc[df['Product ID'] == x]['Price'] = 25` and it shows nothing on my dataframe.

Comment: sorry. missed a `,`  try again (fixed in code above)

Comment: thanks! I also tried a more basic method of just passing each loop to an empty list then passing that list into the df which worked on this small one. Your answer worked too. Thanks!